# Why ProduceRequestData use ImplicitLinkedHashCollection hold topicData

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am reading the source code of kafka producer recently. ProduceRequestData is a step in kafka producer processing request data. In ProduceRequestData, ImplicitLinkedHashCollection is used to store data. The documentation of ImplicitLinkedHashCollection says that it is a memory-efficient hash set which tracks the order of insertion of elements . But in ProduceRequestData I don't see any reason to tracks the order of insertion of TopicProduceData.

Can someone help explain?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka records are ordered by offset. Any data sent by a producer is first buffered in memory before any network request is made towards the broker server.

If the producer send actions were not ordered, then you would receive out-of-order data at the broker, and thereby in the consumer.